# How to find the prime factorization of a very large number.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

I want to know if there are any tricks or shortcuts to write the factorial of a large number, like $20!,$ as the product of its prime factors. 
For example, $5!= 5 \times 3 \times 2^3$

Comment: without using calculators, because this question appears in an mathematics contest

Comment: Given $n!$, it is enough to know the factorizations of 1 to $n$, e.g., $2 = 2^1 \times 3^0 \times 5^0$, $3 = 2^0 \times 3^1 \times 5^0$, $4 = 2^2 \times 3^0 \times 5^0$, $5 = 2^0 \times 3^0 \times 5^1$, so then $5! = 2^3 \times 3^1 \times 5^1$.